# changing UIImageView frame size programmatically

Tags: ios, uiimageview, frame

I have a `UImageView` with initial dimensions set from the `xib` as:

**Y: 0, Height: 406.**

In the `viewDidLoad`, depending on a condition I am using this code:

```
self.mainAdImg.frame = CGRectMake(self.mainAdImg.frame.origin.x, self.mainAdImg.frame.origin.y + OFFSET, self.mainAdImg.frame.size.width, self.mainAdImg.frame.size.height);
```

where `mainAdImg is the UIImageView, and OFFSET is 20.0f`

So, I would expect, the image to go down `20.0`.

Instead the new values become:

```
Y : 20 (correct), height: 426 (not expected)
```

why the height changes?

Edit:

I am not using autolayout.

i log the origin,height like this:

```
NSLog(@" Y : %f, height : %f",self.mainAdImg.frame.origin.y,self.mainAdImg.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: What auto resizing / layout are you using? How are you logging the frame?

Comment: self.mainAdImg.frame.size,height should be self.mainAdImg.frame.size.height maybe?

Comment: disregard the typo, the question is why the height changes?

Comment: What you get as height before changing frame size? Put NSLog to print out height before you change the frame size.

Comment: Auto resizing? Running on iPhone 5 but XIB is iPhone 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    // Do your resizing
}
```

In `viewDidLoad` the view is just loaded, which is too early too rely on frame values. The view doesn't have a superview and autoresizingmasks and auto layout rules can change frame values.

If you still want to do it in `viewDidLoad` you need to use fixed frame values (e.g. `CGRectMake(10,10,600,400)`).